# Laravel FormRequest Before Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-validation

I was looking for a way to validate some logic before the formRequest validation but i couldn't find anything. Does it have some similar hook like `after()` within the `withValidator` method or maybe the constructor?

MyController:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
 public function myMethod(MyFormRequest $request) {
 //the request is validate before executing anything here
 }
}
```

MyFormRequest:

```
class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;

    public function rules(): array
    {

        return [
            'name' => 'integer',
            //etc
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
    {
      if ($this->request->model()->someValue < 100) {
       //throw validation error before the validation of the above rules
      } 
    }
}
```

I can't put the validation in the normal `rules` set because i don't have that attribute in the request data, that specific validation is on a model on the request something tied to the session(like a user model) that i need to check first before anything else but i also can't put it in the `authorization` method or middleware because is not an auth check.

I can always add it in the `prepareForValidation` but then i'd have an attribute in the validatedData that i don't need further in the flow...

Comment: You can use the service provider to write use custom logic using `Validator::extend()` in boot method

Comment: the thing is that custom validation rule from `Validator::extend()` still needs to be mapped to a request input data attribute but in my case i don't have an input attribute but a model on the request bag that i need to validate against, check the snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can always add it in the prepareForValidation but then i'd have an attribute in the validatedData that i don't need further in the flow* - **NO! You don't have to**

Try this. This will come to function and throw the validation which you desire.

```
public function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    if ($this->request->model()->someValue < 100) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'custom_error' => 'Error Message goes here.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

As well there is a feature called [`stopOnFirstFailure`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#request-stopping-on-first-validation-rule-failure)

```
protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;
```

Comment: sry for the late response, your suggestion works just fine for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1:** As you're not validating the form inputs, consider moving this part of validation elsewhere. Middleware may be a good candidate.

**Suggestion 2:** If you want this logic to be in one place, try overriding one of the following methods (not sure which one you need): `validate`, `validateWithBag`, `validateResolved`. You will do something like this:

```
public function validate(array $rules, mixed $params)
{
    if ($this->request->model()->someValue < 100) {
       //throw validation error before the validation of the above rules
    } 

    parent::validate($rules, $params);
}
```

A potential downside of this approach may be that your custom validation will happen before `authorize` or `prepareForValidation`.